# What is the logical location to install IPython-notebook-extensions to in OSX

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions#installation says:

> simply [...] install the conda package. The conda package can be built
>   by running `conda build IPython-notebook-extensions` in the **parent
>   directory**, and then doing a `conda install nbextensions`.

What does it mean by the parent directory?  `~/anaconda/` ?

What is the logically correct (or most sensible) location to install to?

EDIT: someone has suggested my jupyter profile directory, i.e. `~/.jupyter` but this is empty so does this make sense?

Looking through the documentation,
http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/index.html
http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/development/config.html
...maybe I should be using `~/.ipython`

In fact that already contains:

```
README extensions nbextensions profile_default
```

This suggests maybe I already have it installed?  So, following the original documentation:

> After installation, simply go to the /nbextensions/ page in the
>   notebook to activate/deactivate your notebook extensions.

I tried http://localhost:8888/nbextensions and http://localhost:8888/tree/nbextensions but both fail.

I'm frustrated by this README.

ok it links to the wiki https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki which links to https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Home-4.x-%28Jupyter%29

And this page says:

> The nbextension directory has moved to a different location and can be
>   found in one of these directories:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
> from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir, jupyter_path
> print(jupyter_data_dir())
> print(jupyter_path())
> ```

Which yields:

```
/Users/pi/Library/Jupyter
['/Users/pi/Library/Jupyter', '/Users/pi/anaconda/share/jupyter', '/usr/local/share/jupyter', '/usr/share/jupyter']
```

None of which matches `~/.jupyter`

How does anyone figure this out? This is a mess! Maybe the answer is to just install it alongside anaconda, i.e. in `~`, but that doesn't seem right.

EDIT: I have opened an issue: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/issues/418

Comment: I guess in the parent directory of the repository.